# Using embedded Tomcat 8, how can I initialize the Websocket Containter if the tomcat-embed-websocket.jar is not in the class path?

Tags: java-websocket, embedded-tomcat-8, runnable-jar

I am using a runnable jar (with-depenencies) to start an embedded tomcat that hosts a webapplication which uses struts2 and websockets.

The application works propperly when running in an `Tomcat` installation, but when run from the mentioned runnable jar, the websocket container is not initialized, resulting in `404` responses when trying to connect to the corresponding end point.

I narrowed the problem to the discovery processes which reads the `META-INF/Services/javax.servlet.ServerContainerInitializer` of the different jar files to find the classes that initialize services for the server. In particular, the class that initializes the Websockets Container is `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci`.

As far as I can see the `WsSci` class has been repackaged in the runnable jar by the maven assembly plugin, but the `META-INF/Services/javax.servlet.ServerContainerInitializer` file doesn't mention this class in the way the original jar did, it only mentions the `org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer` initializer.

Is there any way I could leave the runnable jar as it is and programatically request the `WebSockets Container` initializacion by calling some method on the `Tomcat` class? Or request the initialization in a `web.xml` file?

Note: as a work arround I could see that if I add the `WsSci` class manually to the 
new `META-INF/Services/javax.servlet.ServerContainerInitializer` file in the runnable jar, the `Websockets Containter` initializes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem, problem could be claassloader,

Tomcat loads ServerContainerInitializer from parent classloader

```
    String configFile = "META-INF/services/" + serviceType.getName();
    ClassLoader loader = this.context.getParentClassLoader();
```

Probably in your tomcat initialization code , you could set to use your classloader instead of webApp classloader.

tomcatContext.setParentClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());